# Laurent Series Expansion Coefficient.

Tags: complex-analysis

For the function $f(z)={1\over z}$ where $z_0=1.$

I'm not exactly sure how they get $c_n=(-1)^n$ using the formula for finding the coefficient.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It's just the geometric series $\frac{1}{1+z} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n z^n$, implying $\frac{1}{z} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n (z-1)^n$. It can be derived from Cauchy's formula as well, but this could very well be circular logic somewhere..